# Ansible fact is undefined error in conditional

Tags: mongodb, ansible, yaml, ansible-facts

Below is the playbook

```
---
- name: stop agent process
  shell: "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -w {{ MONGODB_AGENT_PROCESS }} | awk '{print $2}'"
  register: running_agent_processes
- name: stop mongod process
  shell: "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -w {{ MONGODB_SERVER_PROCESS  }} | awk '{print $2}'"
  register: running_mongod_processes
- name: combine processes
  set_fact:
    all_processes: "{{ running_agent_processes.stdout_lines + running_mongod_processes.stdout_lines }}"
- name: Kill all processes
  shell: "kill {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ all_processes }}"
  when: ansible_facts[ansible_hostname] != primary
- wait_for:
    path: "/proc/{{ item }}/status"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ all_processes }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: killed_processes
  when: ansible_facts[ansible_hostname] != primary
- name: Force kill stuck processes
  shell: "kill -9 {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ killed_processes.results | select('failed') | map(attribute='item') | list }}"
  when: ansible_facts[ansible_hostname] != primary
```

I have stored a fact called "primary" which stores the primary of a mongodb replica set in a previous step in the playbook.
I just want to compare the `ansible_facts[ansible_hostname]` with my `primary` fact. If they are not equal, I would like to kill processes.

The error I am getting is below:

> fatal: [lpdkubpoc01d.phx.aexp.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The
> conditional check 'ansible_facts[ansible_hostname] != primary' failed.
> The error was: error while evaluating conditional
> (ansible_facts[ansible_hostname] != primary): 'ansible_facts' is
> undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in
> '/idn/home/sanupin/stop-enterprise-mongodb/tasks/stopAutomationAgent.yml':
> line 11, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the
> exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n
> all_processes: "{{ running_agent_processes.stdout_lines +
> running_mongod_processes.stdout_lines }}"\n- name: Kill all
> processes\n  ^ here\n"} fatal: [lpdkubpoc01c.phx.aexp.com]: FAILED! =>
> {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_facts[ansible_hostname] !=
> primary' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional
> (ansible_facts[ansible_hostname] != primary): 'ansible_facts' is
> undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in
> '/idn/home/sanupin/stop-enterprise-mongodb/tasks/stopAutomationAgent.yml':
> line 11, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the
> exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n
> all_processes: "{{ running_agent_processes.stdout_lines +
> running_mongod_processes.stdout_lines }}"\n- name: Kill all
> processes\n  ^ here\n"} fatal: [lpdkubpoc01e.phx.aexp.com]: FAILED! =>
> {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_facts[ansible_hostname] !=
> primary' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional
> (ansible_facts[ansible_hostname] != primary): 'ansible_facts' is
> undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in
> '/idn/home/sanupin/stop-enterprise-mongodb/tasks/stopAutomationAgent.yml':
> line 11, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the
> exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n
> all_processes: "{{ running_agent_processes.stdout_lines +
> running_mongod_processes.stdout_lines }}"\n- name: Kill all
> processes\n  ^ here\n"}

Can someone help me with comparing an ansible_fact with a set_fact fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can comparing use directly ansible facts without write `ansible_facts` before. Just use as `when: ansible_hostname != primary`